# How to get View SQL Query within C#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I need to get View SQL Query to display it in some text box within C# CODE level.
Each View is build upon part e.g. `Select x From table` and I want to retrieve it in my C# code, only that query using View name I already know.
How to achieve this in C# maybe using ADO.NET?

Comment: TOTALLY database server dependant. What you use? MySql? Oracle? Apple Pie?

Comment: not sure to understand your question ... Maybe `Select id, firstname, lastname from view_contacts` ?

Comment: Can't use SQL Server Profiler cause I want to have it in C# code not to just View this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ADO.Net `SqlDataAdapter` object's `SelectCommand` property to get the select query associated with the dataset/datatable, assuming this is what you want...

Below is the MSDN link for explanation of `SelectCommand` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx

OK, if you want the underlying query for your `database VIEW`, then as it is stored on the database server, you can only get it by executing the stored procedure `sp_helptext 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME'` in sql management studio or even from ADO.Net in C#/VB.Net. Refer link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you need DB schema. Maybe information from [Retrieve all Views from DbConnection (for common DB types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861443/retrieve-all-views-from-dbconnection-for-common-db-types) can be useful for you.